# For the periodic sequence, is there always an algebraic closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, closed-form

This question is a generalized form of the problem I asked before:

[Algebraic Closed Form for $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\left( n- 3 \lfloor \frac{n-1}{3} \rfloor\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3065950/548054)

> Let, look at this periodic sequence:
>
> $$a_n=\left\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\cdots a_k ; a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5, \cdots a_k; a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\cdots a_k;\cdots \right\}$$, where $\left\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots a_k \right\} \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and $a_{k+1}=a_1, a_{k+2}=a_2, a_{k+3}=a_3, \cdots a_{2k}=a_k, \cdots$

For the sequence $a_k=\left\{ a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_k \right\}$ , $k$ is a finite number. $a_1,a_2,...a_k$ are arbitary numbers.

Verbally, the series $a_n$ consists of an infinite number of periodic repetitions of the finite series $a_k.$

> Finally my question is:
>
> a) If there is an exist a algebraic closed form, for finite series $a_k$, in this case, does the $ a_n $ series always have a algebraic closed form?
>
> b) If there is not an exist a algebraic closed form, for finite series $a_k$, in this case, does the $ a_n $ series always have a algebraic closed form?

I mean ,for example:

> a)
>
> $a_n=\left\{ 1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7,1,3,5,7\cdots\right\}$
>
> b)
>
> $a_n=\left\{1,8,2,6,5,9,1,8,2,6,5,9,1,8,2,6,5,9,1,8,2,6,5,9\cdots\right\}$

Thank you very much.

Comment: A finite sequence always does have a closed form, and so does a periodic sequence.

Comment: @RobertIsrael for any arbitary numbers for $a_1, a_2,a_3,...a_k$, There's an always closed form for $a_n$. Do I understand correct?

Comment: @Beginner, it depends on what you consider a "closed form". That term is not really well-defined. In a sense you have given a "closed form" in your definition of the sequence.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I tried to give 2 example for a good understanding of the question..

Comment: This might be a closed form for your first sequence:
$$
a_k = \begin{cases}
1&\text{if $k = 1 \mod4$,}\\
3&\text{if $k = 2 \mod4$,}\\
5&\text{if $k = 3 \mod4$,}\\
7&\text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
Does that satisfy what you're looking for in a "closed form"?

Comment: @Beginner You have **not** defined what you mean by "closed form". Until you do so, your question is meaningless.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I edited the question. I mean algebraic closed form.

Comment: @Somos I edited the question.

Comment: @Beginner, this is still vague. "Algebraic" is not a formal term. What algebraic operations are allowed? Is case distinction not OK? Is using the remainder function (as the current answer does) not OK?

Comment: @MeesdeVries You are right..such as the answer given in the link I added to the question. I couldn't describe it mathematically. I'm sorry..

Comment: There is no need to interpret my direct tone as criticism -- one has to be curt in these comments. :-) I am asking questions because I want to understand you, and help you understand your problem. The linked question uses the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ -- that apparently is allowed. Thus you certainly allow more than the ordinary algebraic operations $+, \times, -, /, {}^{\wedge}$. If you can tell us exactly what operations are allowed we may be able to help you.

Comment: More generally though: I think you are looking for something that is not so important. *Why* do you want a closed form? To satisfy your curiosity?

Comment: @MeesdeVries Of course, this is not a dry curiosity. You are right. All algebraic operations and floor function+ trigonometric form are possible . Without $\mod$ operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A periodic sequence with period $P$ can always be written as a trigonometric polynomial $$a_n = \sum_{j=0}^{P-1} b_j \cos(2 \pi j n/P) + \sum_{j=1}^{P-1} c_j \sin(2 \pi j n/P)$$
for some coefficients $b_j$ and $c_j$ (look up Finite Fourier Transform).

Thus your first example can be written as
$$a_n = 4-\cos \left( \pi\,j/2 \right) -\cos \left( \pi\,j \right) -\cos
 \left( 3\,\pi\,j/2 \right) -\sin \left( \pi\,j/2 \right) +\sin
 \left( 3\,\pi\,j/2 \right) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial interpolating $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_k$.

Then the sequence is given by $a_n = f(1+((n-1) \bmod k))$.

If you can't use mod directly, but can use floor, then note that
$$
a \bmod b = a - b \left\lfloor \dfrac{a}{b} \right\rfloor
$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb N$.